# (jQuery) Change text on click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change text on click. First click `"show"`, next click `"hide"`. I can't figure out what is wrong here.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".card-link:first").click(function() {
if ($(".card-link:first").text('Show comments')) { 
 $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").show(); 
 $(".card-link:first").text('Hide comments');

} else if ($(".card-link:first").text('Hide comments')) {
 $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").hide();
 $(".card-link:first").text('Show comments');
}
  });
});
```

> JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eyc4kxzm/6/

Comment: `if ($('.card-link:first').text('Show comments')) ` this is not how you test if an element contains a text

Comment: also, since you are usinge jsfiddle - please use at least the `tidy` button on top - for the code snipped here on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text()` just sets the text, it doesn't check the current value. You're setting "Show comments" every time, and `text()` is returning that value, so the `if` succeeds and its inner block is called.

Test what `text()` *returns* instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //Hide comments before first click
  $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").hide();

  $(".card-link:first").click(function() {

    if ($(".card-link:first").text() === 'Show comments') {
      $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").show();
      $(".card-link:first").text('Hide comments');
    } 
    else if ($(".card-link:first").text() === 'Hide comments') {
      $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").hide();
      $(".card-link:first").text('Show comments');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card" style="width: 40em; margin: 0 auto;">

    <div class="card-block">
      <a href="#/" class="card-link">Show comments</a>

    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="w-100">
          <h5>List group item heading</h5>
        </div>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the wrong comparison of [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/). It returns the text if no value is passed inside the method & sets the text if there is value.

```
    $(document).ready(function() { //Hide comments before first click
         $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").hide();
         $(".card-link:first").click(function() {
         if ($(".card-link:first").text() == 'Show comments') { 
            $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").show(); 
            $(".card-link:first").text('Hide comments');
         } else if ($(".card-link:first").text() == 'Hide comments') {
            $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").hide();
            $(".card-link:first").text('Show comments');
         }
     });
  });
```

Comment: @julekgwa didn't notice that. let me update it. Thanks man. It was in OP as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery already, you can use jQuery's onDocument load. Additionally it's generally cleaner to add/remove classes appose to checking if text is equal.

```
$(function() {

    $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").hide();

        $(".card-link:first").click(function() {

        if ($(".card-link:first").hasClass("show-comments")) {
            $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").hide();
            $(".card-link:first").text('Show comments');
            $(".card-link:first").removeClass("show-comments");
        } else {
            $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").show(); 
            $(".card-link:first").text('Hide comments');
            $(".card-link:first").addClass("show-comments");
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, seems to be working fine:

```
  $(".card-link:first").click(function() {
    if ($(".card-link:first").text()==='Show comments') { 
      $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").show(); 
      $(".card-link:first").text('Hide comments');
    } else  {
       $("ul.list-group.list-group-flush").hide();
       $(".card-link:first").text('Show comments');
   }
  }
```